# JAXB generates no @XmlRootElement from schema

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I had a problem while generating Java-Classes with JAXB under Java 1.6 where the `@XmlRootElement` Annotation was not generated.
In the Schema file I added the following block to force xjc to set the class name:

```
<xs:annotation>
    <xs:appinfo>
        <jaxb:class name="ClassName" />
    </xs:appinfo>
</xs:annotation>
```

When i **removed** this block, the `@XmlRootElement` Annotation was generated just like i wanted.

Did not find a solution on the internet for this problem but wanted to share it.

Answer (score 3):

When generating classes from an XML Schema a JAXB implementation will generate a class annotated with `@XmlRootElement` for each global element with an anonymous complex type.  Global elements with a named complex type will have an `@XmlElementDecl` annotation on a `create` method on the generated `ObjectFactory` class.

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/07/jaxb-and-root-elements.html

`@XmlRootElement` is unrelated to the JAXB schema annotation you cite in your question.

Comment: The generated ObjectFactory class has and had no such annotated factory method despite being a complex type in the schema. Inlining the complex type inside the element or other "solutions" I found on the internet were not effective.

Comment: @user3012709 - My blog post I linked to gives quite a detailed example.  If you update your question to include an XML schema I can provide more information on your use case.

Comment: Thanks Blaise. How would this work, in the case that the complex type is named, since it contains a sub-element that can refer to another instance of the same complex type? (and that you still want to have `@XmlRootElement`...)